# SNS Topics getting deleted after sometime automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I am using AWS on console itself. I have noticed an issue that when i am creating a SNS topic and i make a subscription and it is confirmed from the receiver. But after an hour or two when i go back the "topics" console i can't see the topic that i have created and when i go to the "subscriptions" console i can see my subscriptions but when i try pressing the hyperlink directing towards my topic, I get this message :

```
Couldn't retrieve topic attributes.
Error code: NotFound - Error message: Topic does not exist
```

Anyone has any idea on why this is happening.
I am not even changing my AWS region in this entire process.
And i have the Full SNS access to my role

Comment: Go to the CloudTrail event history and search for the event name `DeleteTopic`. This will show you information about who/what deleted the topic (eg, user credentials, IP address).